# What is the git equivalent of hg heads / hg parents?

Tags: git

In hg I can use `hg heads` to view all current heads. I still have not been able to find an equivalent in git. The [git-hg rosetta stone](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Git-hg-rosetta-stone) doesn't give an answer.

As for `hg parents` which in hg simply tells the direct ancestors of a node the rosetta stone simply reads the very unhelpful:

```
git log # you can read all the information you need from there (as long as you already know the answer to the question you're asking)
```

Comment: i believe `git branch` is the equivalent of `hg heads`

Comment: @JaredPar A head in Mercurial is a commit with no children. This isn't the same thing as a branch. Some branches may have children. And some commits without children may not be the head of a branch.

Comment: Looks like a X-Y problem. What is it that you want to do in Git? there might be a (better) equivalent to what you want to do rather than an equivalent to what you did in Hg.

Comment: @MichaelMior A head in Mercurial is not just a commit with no children. A head in Mercurial is defined as a commit that has no children _in the same branch_. `hg heads` thus shows all the branches' heads.

Comment: @robert From [the docs](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Head): "A head is a changeset with no child changesets."

Comment: @MichaelMior I'll correct myself: **Branch heads** are changesets that have no child changeset on the same branch. `hg heads` shows all the branch heads. My point is that they may well have children in other branches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git rev-list HEAD`, `git rev-list <sha1>` and `git rev-list HEAD -1 -- file` are the equivalents of the different forms of `hg parents`

As for your detached HEAD problem, doing `git checkout <sha1>` is meant for commit inspection and not for general workflow. If you want a branch off a commit, you have to do `git branch <name> <sha1>` or `git checkout -b <name> <sha1>` and work on it.

Due to the above reason, I feel that it is not ideal to talk of the equivalent to `hg heads` in git as being all commits that don't have a child, but the closes equivalent is `git branch`

Comment: `git rev-list` is hardly equivalent to `hg parents` (or at least not in any of the forms shown in this answer); here's [a question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085248/).

Answer (score 2):

You can view all named heads with `git branch` for branches and `git tag` for tags. I'm sure there's a fancy way to display all heads (i.e. dangling commits) but keep in mind that these may be garbage collected by git under the default settings.

**UPDATE**

I just realized that this is really unrelated to the concept of heads in Mercurial. This will really show you any named revisions in the repository, which may or may not be useful for your purposes.

Comment: `git show-ref` will show you all the refs, branches and tags.

Comment: I think there must be some git concepts I'm missing. This stuff is so simple when I do it with hg, but with git I keep getting detached heads and into states where I can't push/pull/anything. What does it mean that garbage can be collected? If I go to a previously committed revision and start coding against it and commit it should create a new non-named head right? How on earth do I view those?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer You just shouldn't be committing like that when you're in a detached head state.

Comment: If you start coding off a previous revision you should work off of a new branch. You can do this by checking out the revision and then running `git branch NEW_BRANCH_NAME`. git will occasionally remove any commits which aren't referenced anywhere. i.e. are not part of named branch.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Not true. It's a totally normal technique if you need to test something off an old revision. I wouldn't say it's commonly used, but there are valid use cases.

Comment: I think the detached head concept is one that I'm missing (and sadly one that I'm now stuck in) Is there a similar concept in mercurial that I can compare against to fix it?

Comment: @MichaelMior Testing something off an old revision does not usually involve committing while *in* that state. I agree with you that if you do this you should bring it out into a branch and that is okay, but actually committing while in a detached head state makes no sense to me.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I would just create a new branch off the commit you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

As a substitute for `hg heads`, I use:

```
git log --no-walk --parents --abbrev-commit --all
```

(note that you can combine this with further filters, such as `--committer`, including format filters)

As a substitute for `hg parents`, I use:

```
git log --no-walk --format='format:%P%n' HEAD
```